# How can I update or change cost price (standard price) in odoo v13 postgresql database?

Tags: database, postgresql, odoo, odoo-13

I am trying to change the cost price of products in Odoov13 in postgresql database, can anyone please support me with an example or guide? The question is simple, there is a selling price and a cost price (standard price) on the products, I just try to change the cost price, not the selling price, but I don't know how to get to the table or column, the Only reference I have is that the value can be stored in property field, but I don't know how to access it.

```
SELECT * FROM ir_property WHERE name = 'standard_price';
```

Answer (score 2):

Fini

The field `standard_price` is **computed** field without **store**=True So it can store the data into `postgres` **database**.

If you want to update the field value, You can make the `server-action` following step:

1. Goto Settings->Server Actions
2. **Model** :  `Product Template`
3. **Action To Do**: `Update the Record`
4. **Data to Write**:

   - Field : `Cost (product.template)`
   - Evaluation Type: `Value`
   - Value: Add your value example,  `112`

make the `Create Contextual Action`

Goto `Product template` and `refresh` the page on the `action` you can find the created server action and execute.